# How to mock someObj.meth1(...).meth2(...)?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I have a mock of map object

```
@Mock
Map<String, Object> statusNode;
```

I have written this to reduce the amount of code

```
when(statusNode.get("ratePlanId")).thenReturn(
                    when(mock(Number.class).longValue()).thenReturn(200L).getMock()
    );
```

but it throw exception:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException:
```

I can to do it by use other way, but it's too much code, and i should use exsessive operation of the variable initialization

```
Number number = mock(Number.class);
when(number.longValue()).thenReturn(100L);
when(statusNode.get("subscriberStatusId")).thenReturn(number);
```

The common case is: How to mock something like this without  operation of the variable initialization?

```
someObj.get("standardId").longValue();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the first `when` has already run when you start stubbing the second mock.  In Mockito, you can only stub one method at a time.  What you could do is assign the inner mock to a local variable like this.

```
Number innerMock = when(mock(Number.class).longValue()).thenReturn(200L).getMock();
when(statusNode.get("ratePlanId")).thenReturn(innerMock);
```

This will work.  But, mocking types that you don't own is a bit of a testing anti-pattern.  If you can test this without mocking the `Number` class, that would be better.

```
when(statusNode.get("ratePlanId")).thenReturn(Long.valueOf(200L));
```

Comment: In Mockito, you can only stub one method at a time. Why is it problem?

Comment: It's a problem because of the way Mockito is designed.  When you call `when`, it switches into a kind of "stubbing mode" where calling a method on a mock sets it up for stubbing.  Once you're in "stubbing mode", Mockito doesn't let you call `when` again until you've finished the stubbing.

Comment: Thanks for when(statusNode.get("ratePlanId")).thenReturn(Long.valueOf(200L)); i'll use it and thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Map<String, Object> statusNode = mock(Map.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
```

And then mock subcalls:

```
when(statusNode.get("subscriberStatusId").longValue()).thenReturn(100L);
```

You might need casting:

```
when(((Number) statusNode.get("subscriberStatusId")).longValue()).thenReturn(100L);
```

Comment: Thanks, i can to do so but i need when(statusNode.get("name").longValue()).thenReturn(100L) get are returned instance of object class which hasn't a longValue() method

Comment: You can't do that, because hashCode return primitive int type, while you can override only objects. It works only for methods that return Object children

Comment: For my case your example isn't working. Because map store Objects, which will Numbers in real.

Comment: Anyway thanks a lot, i don't know about this specific feature.

Answer (score 0):

Giving an answer from a different point of view: consider avoiding such code.

Yes, a lot of people are advocating these "fluent" interfaces where you type foo.bar().whatever().

But there is one bad thing about that: it is a violation of the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter); and therefore it increases the coupling between your classes!

But sure, in your concrete example, you probably don't care, because calling longValue() on a Number object isn't a big deal.